# Expression of type 'System.Func`1[System.Threading.Tasks.Task]' cannot be used for return type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task'

Tags: c#

So, I'm using the below assignment:

```
Expression<Func<Task>> a = Expression.Lambda<Func<Task>>(() => Task.CompletedTask);
```

And it results in the error mentioned in the thread subject:

> Expression of type 'System.Func`1[System.Threading.Tasks.Task]' cannot
> be used for return type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task'

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong...

Comment: That code already compiles for me with no problem. Please provide more details with a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing the `Expression.Lambda`, compiler should be able to figure out the conversions itself:

```
Expression<Func<Task>> a = () => Task.CompletedTask;
```